# Unable to start embedded Tomcat whe all Report Services are deployed on AWS FARGATE ECS Containers

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, reportportal

I am using AWS FARGATE ECS to host Report Portal. We have hosted Postgres in AWS RDS. Out of 11 services, we able to deploy 10 services in ECS. Last remaining service is API . To deploy these, we have created Cluster, Task Definitions with containers. The, we create Tasks and start them.

Getting error as unable to start embedded tomcat.

```
               API Service: 5.1.0
                Built with ♡ by EPAM Systems
                Spring Boot  (v2.2.5.RELEASE)
2020-05-02 02:22:16.755  INFO 11 --- [           main] c.e.t.r.core.configs.ReportPortalApp     : Starting ReportPortalApp on ip-10-0-1-59.ap-south-1.compute.internal with PID 11 (/service-api-5.1.0-exec.jar started by root in /)
2020-05-02 02:22:16.836  INFO 11 --- [           main] c.e.t.r.core.configs.ReportPortalApp     : The following profiles are active: default
2020-05-02 02:22:25.338  INFO 11 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2020-05-02 02:22:26.647  INFO 11 --- [           main] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 1299ms. Found 30 JPA repository interfaces.
2020-05-02 02:22:37.056  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.ObjectPostProcessorConfiguration] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.145  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectPostProcessor' of type [org.springframework.security.config.annotation.configuration.AutowireBeanFactoryObjectPostProcessor] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.150  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler@1cc9cfb2' of type [org.springframework.security.access.expression.method.DefaultMethodSecurityExpressionHandler] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.157  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'userRoleHierarchy' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.UserRoleHierarchy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.160  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'securityConfiguration' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.SecurityConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$2bca0c92] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.238  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'permissionEvaluator' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.PermissionEvaluatorFactoryBean] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.340  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'projectManagerPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.ProjectManagerPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.450  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSourceConfig' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.config.DataSourceConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7b53bf4d] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:37.654  INFO 11 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Starting...
2020-05-02 02:22:39.056  INFO 11 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Start completed.
2020-05-02 02:22:39.058  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'dataSource' of type [com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.260  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'spring.datasource-org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceProperties] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.452  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker' of type [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializerInvoker] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.535  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'ACLContext' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.ACLContext$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$6e333ceb] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.852  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'coffeinCache' of type [org.springframework.cache.caffeine.CaffeineCache] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.948  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'permissionGrantingStrategy' of type [org.springframework.security.acls.domain.DefaultPermissionGrantingStrategy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.955  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclAuthorizationStrategy' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.acl.ReportPortalAclAuthorizationStrategyImpl] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:39.957  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclCache' of type [org.springframework.security.acls.domain.SpringCacheBasedAclCache] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.046  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'lookupStrategy' of type [org.springframework.security.acls.jdbc.BasicLookupStrategy] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.059  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclService' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.acl.ReportPortalAclService] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.147  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclPermissionEvaluator' of type [org.springframework.security.acls.AclPermissionEvaluator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.151  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclFullPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.AclFullPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.236  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'aclReadPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.AclReadPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.243  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'assignedToProjectPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.AssignedToProjectPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.250  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'notCustomerPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.NotCustomerPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.252  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'reporterPermission' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.ReporterPermission] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.255  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'permissionEvaluator' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.auth.permissions.ReportPortalPermissionEvaluator] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.256  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'securityConfiguration.MethodSecurityConfig' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.SecurityConfiguration$MethodSecurityConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$998bc8f7] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.437  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'methodSecurityMetadataSource' of type [org.springframework.security.access.method.DelegatingMethodSecurityMetadataSource] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:40.560  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jacksonConfiguration' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.JacksonConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$3275d909] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:42.437  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'objectMapper' of type [com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:43.139  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'jsonConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:43.158  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'stringConverter' of type [org.springframework.http.converter.StringHttpMessageConverter] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:43.242  INFO 11 --- [           main] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'mvcConfig' of type [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.MvcConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$fe4171f8] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2020-05-02 02:22:47.353  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8585 (http)
2020-05-02 02:22:47.448  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2020-05-02 02:22:47.448  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.31]
2020-05-02 02:22:47.849  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2020-05-02 02:22:47.849  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 30799 ms
2020-05-02 02:22:52.435  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [name: default]
2020-05-02 02:22:53.036  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.4.12.Final
2020-05-02 02:22:54.335  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.0.Final}
2020-05-02 02:22:58.444  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: com.epam.ta.reportportal.commons.JsonbAwarePostgresDialect
2020-05-02 02:23:09.639  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.h.e.t.j.p.i.JtaPlatformInitiator       : HHH000490: Using JtaPlatform implementation: [org.hibernate.engine.transaction.jta.platform.internal.NoJtaPlatform]
2020-05-02 02:23:09.650  INFO 11 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-05-02 02:23:10.151  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Using default implementation for ThreadExecutor
2020-05-02 02:23:10.243  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl    : Initialized Scheduler Signaller of type: class org.quartz.core.SchedulerSignalerImpl
2020-05-02 02:23:10.244  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Quartz Scheduler v.2.3.2 created.
2020-05-02 02:23:10.256  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : Using db table-based data access locking (synchronization).
2020-05-02 02:23:10.258  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore     : JobStoreCMT initialized.
2020-05-02 02:23:10.258  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler meta-data: Quartz Scheduler (v2.3.2) 'reportportal' with instanceId 'api:3d399a8ccb9a8c7800a1c62f702319d1'
  Scheduler class: 'org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler' - running locally.
  NOT STARTED.
  Currently in standby mode.
  Number of jobs executed: 0
  Using thread pool 'org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool' - with 1 threads.
  Using job-store 'org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.LocalDataSourceJobStore' - which supports persistence. and is clustered.
2020-05-02 02:23:10.258  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler 'reportportal' initialized from an externally provided properties instance.
2020-05-02 02:23:10.258  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory      : Quartz scheduler version: 2.3.2
2020-05-02 02:23:10.258  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : JobFactory set to: com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.SchedulerConfiguration$1@3c20e9d6
2020-05-02 02:25:22.440 ERROR 11 --- [           main] o.s.b.web.embedded.tomcat.TomcatStarter  : Error starting Tomcat context. Exception: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException. Message: Error creating bean with name 'servletEndpointRegistrar' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/web/ServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration$WebMvcServletEndpointManagementContextConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.web.ServletEndpointRegistrar]: Factory method 'servletEndpointRegistrar' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'infoEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/info/InfoEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.info.InfoEndpoint]: Factory method 'infoEndpoint' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'infoContributorComposite' defined in URL [jar:file:/service-api-5.1.0-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/epam/ta/reportportal/info/InfoContributorComposite.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'analyzerInfoContributor' defined in URL [jar:file:/service-api-5.1.0-exec.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/epam/ta/reportportal/info/AnalyzerInfoContributor.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'managementTemplate' defined in class path resource [com/epam/ta/reportportal/core/configs/rabbit/AnalyzerRabbitMqConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.analyzer.auto.client.RabbitMqManagementClient]: Factory method 'managementTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on PUT request for "http://15.206.28.47:15672/api/vhosts/analyzer": Connect to 15.206.28.47:15672 [/15.206.28.47] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out); nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 15.206.28.47:15672 [/15.206.28.47] failed: Connection timed out (Connection timed out)
2020-05-02 02:25:22.548  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-05-02 02:25:22.635  WARN 11 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
2020-05-02 02:25:22.635  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.s.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean        : Shutting down Quartz Scheduler
2020-05-02 02:25:22.635  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler reportportal_$_api:3d399a8ccb9a8c7800a1c62f702319d1 shutting down.
2020-05-02 02:25:22.635  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler reportportal_$_api:3d399a8ccb9a8c7800a1c62f702319d1 paused.
2020-05-02 02:25:22.753  INFO 11 --- [           main] org.quartz.core.QuartzScheduler          : Scheduler reportportal_$_api:3d399a8ccb9a8c7800a1c62f702319d1 shutdown complete.
2020-05-02 02:25:22.762  INFO 11 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-05-02 02:25:22.834  INFO 11 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-05-02 02:25:22.943  INFO 11 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-05-02 02:25:22.950 ERROR 11 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server; nested exception is org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:156)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
    at com.epam.ta.reportportal.core.configs.ReportPortalApp.main(ReportPortalApp.java:37)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:51)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:52)
Caused by: org.springframework.boot.web.server.WebServerException: Unable to start embedded Tomcat
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the error:

```
Exception: I/O error on PUT request for 
"http://15.206.28.47:15672/api/vhosts/analyzer": 
Connect to 15.206.28.47:15672 [/15.206.28.47] failed: Connection timed out 
(Connection timed out);
```

your RabbitMQ instance is not accessible or VHOST `analyzer` is not created.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is that it can't connect to `15.206.28.47` during startup.